# tuleap: How to incorporate hierarchy among artifacts within a tracker?

Tags: tuleap

tuleap: How to incorporate hierarchy among artifacts on the same tracker? For instance, in capturing requirements, a requirement may lead to several sub-rqmts. I want to highlight the hierarchy among them and ensure that unless the child rqmts are closed, the parent rqmt doesnt get closed

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your issue is to have a separate tracker for sub-requirements and set-up a hierarchy between them. You can then add triggers in the tracker administration workflow section in order to automatically close requirements when all the sub-requirements are closed. You can also modify the permissions on the requirements' status field to prevent some users from closing the requirements by hand.